The // operator is returning a floating number when one input is floating. Documents say it does integer division, returning the floor
Created my example in a shell script copied here.
Python 3.12.5  on win32
Using a float for the dividend:
>>> 12345.342424 // 1000
12.0

>>> import math
>>> math.floor(12345.342424 / 1000)
12

With the divisor a float, the result is similar:
>>> 12345 // 12.0
1028.0
>>> math.floor(12345 / 12.0)
1028

My minimal examples are above.
Related posts assure me that // and floor are synonyms.

The are not, indeed cannot, be synonyms. floor is unrelated to division, even if // performs a type of flooring operation.

I think they mean // and floor(/)

But even then, the equivalence isn't true. Because of floating point error, a/b might slightly less than a//b, so floor() will round down to a//b-1

Related posts? What related posts? Note that floor is not just a function in the math module, it's also a well-known function in mathematics.

Yeah it does integer division, returning the floor, but did the document say it uses math.floor()? the built-in floor in definition of // arises from lower language c.

This answer relates to python 3.
As written in PEP 238, a//b will first coerce a and b into the same type, and then return the floor division in the same type.

Specifically, if a and b are of the same type, a//b will be of that type too. If the inputs are of different types, they are first coerced to a common type using the same rules used for all other arithmetic operators.


For floating point inputs, the result is a float. For example:
3.5//2.0 == 1.0


This means that although the // operator will perform floor division, the return value will not necessarily be an integral type.
In comparison, the math.floor() function will always return an integral type.
